# How can I do a while loop that works regardless of what direction the loop goes?

Tags: python

I have a forloop that looks like this, I use it to slowly increase the volume of a speaker in a home automation wakeup-alarm-system.

```
while vol < max:
    if datetime.datetime.now() > next:
       next = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=rate);
       vol = vol + increment
       func(vol)
```

1, I know this is a horrible practice, but my envrioment (rasberry pi) does not support time.sleep. Am open to other suggestions!

2, Sometimes, vol > max to begin with. Increment will be calculated to a negative number automatically, but the loop will ofcourse just be skipped. Can I somehow do a loop that works regardless of if vol or max is bigger?

Comment: You want to loop regardless of whether vol>max or vol<max? Just do a while True and then write a case that will break the loop or set it as False?

Comment: And what exits the loop when vol>Max? when it becomes smaller?

Comment: @anishtain4, i added some details to make my code more understandable

Comment: `while vol != max` unless your increment is not 1 or -1...

Comment: @MarkTolonen this doesn't stop the loop if vol doesn't land exactly on max, if they're float points this is a recipe for infinite loop

Comment: @anishtain4 Hence "unless your increment is not 1 or -1".  There's no indication that it is floating point.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: `vol=13, max=10,increment=2`

Comment: @anishtain4 No kidding, which is why I qualified my comment that the increment would have to be -1 or 1.  The OP should clarify the exact requirements instead of making them up.

Comment: @MarkTolonen i don't have increments of one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should go linearly toward max (given that increment is chosen by you):

```
while (max-vol)*numpy.sign(increment)>0:
    vol+=increment
    func(vol)
```